# Custom toast activity-independent

Tags: android, toast

Can I, in Android, display a custom toast or any custom control that won't disappear on navigation?

I'm currently adding my custom own toast implementation (which is a view, not a toast) to the decor view, but it disappears as soon as I navigate to another activity.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? A Toast will "evaporate" after some millis. A Dialog waits for an interaction before closing. A DialogFragment can be incorporated as part of the design. A TextView or a Webview can be permanent... so, what do you need to show and how?

Comment: I think you'll need a separate `Window` for that. (I know next to nothing about Android's `Window` system, but you may be able to find something with enough searching...)

Comment: @Vyger A message in a box that shows and hides, or can be sticky with checkbox or buttons, but doesn't disappear if user navigate out.

Comment: A `Toast` does not disappear based upon navigation. It remains on the screen for the specified duration.

Comment: In facts, as I said, it `will "evaporate" after some millis`.

Comment: So, maybe you just need a simple TextView to show some text - and you can make it VISIBLE OR INVISIBLE (or even GONE) at your will.

Comment: Well, it is obvious that the layout will contain a text view. What I'm searching for is a way to keep it alive when navigating.